# HTML 5: AudioContext AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, web-audio-api

I need to understand how audio buffer works and to do it I want to make the following sequence: `Microphone-> Auto-> Processor-> Manual-> Buffer-> Auto-> Speakers`. Auto means auto data transfer and manual I do myself via the code in `processor.onaudioprocess`. So I have the following code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
var audioContext;
var myAudioBuffer;
var microphone;
var speakers;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {audio: true}, 
        function(stream) {
            audioContext = new AudioContext();
            //STEP 1 - we create buffer and its node
            speakers = audioContext.destination;
            myAudioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 22050, 44100);
            var bufferNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            bufferNode.buffer = myAudioBuffer;
            bufferNode.connect(speakers);
            bufferNode.start();

            //STEP 2- we create microphone and processor
            microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            var processor = (microphone.context.createScriptProcessor || 
                microphone.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(microphone.context,4096, 1, 1);
            processor.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
                var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
                var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // we have only one channel
                var nowBuffering = myAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
                for (var sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
                  nowBuffering[sample] = inputData[sample];
                }
            }

            microphone.connect(processor);                    

        },
        function() {
            console.log("Error 003.")
        });
}
```

However, this code doesn't work. No errors, only silence. Where is my mistake?

Comment: try logging errors instead of throwing them away: `function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}` becomes `function(e){ console.error(e)}`, and see if the message helps.

Comment: Which browser/OS versions are you using?

Comment: @ManoDestra FF 47/ Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting silence (i.e. your onprocess is getting called, but the buffers are empty) or nothing (i.e. your onprocess is never getting called)?

If the latter, try connecting the scriptprocessor to the context.destination.  Even if you don't use the output, some implementations currently need that connection to pull data through.

Comment: So which is it?  Are you getting arrays of empty values, or just not getting .onaudioprocess called?

Comment: onaudioprocess is called and I hear nothing. I tried to connect processor to buffer node but it also didn't help. I can't understand what the problem as algorithm how to write to buffer I took from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode

Comment: I've read that you are expert in web audio. Could give me hint to my problem. In few words: I need to divide my program to two parts. The first (micro+processor), the second (???+speakers) and make them independent from each other. The question is how to play array of samples in the second part in cycle - samples from microphone but the second part mustn't use microphone anyhow and mustn't know about it.

Comment: Actually, this WAS the answer to OP's problem - connecting the scriptprocessor to context.destination.  A single line added below "microphone.connect(processor);" reading "processor.connect(speakers);" fixed the problem of "I'm not getting any data from the microphone".  (since you're not copying anything to the output buffer in onaudioprocess, it will still produce silence.)

As to the problem of "I'm not hearing anything" - you're creating, then playing an AudioBuffer (via a BufferSourceNode).  You never copy any data into it, so of course it's silent.

Comment: As an aside, you won't be able to write data into a buffer that's already playing.  (That can cause a race condition - the buffer is silently copied.  This is in the spec - https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#acquire-the-content - but it's a bit obscure.)  You'll need to copy data to a buffer that's NOT scheduled to play, and then schedule it.

Comment: So, do I underestand you right: I need for every new array of sample create new buffer and then schedule it to play?

Comment: Sort of.  You don't need to create a new buffer every time - you can reuse buffers, but only when they're not currently playing or scheduled to play.  So you can create a set of buffers, and reuse each one once they're done playing.  (The simplest thing to do is to create a new one each time; but you may not want to have that much memory allocation/deallocation happening.)

Comment: Thank you very very much. This is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

### EDIT

So since the OP definitely wants to use a buffer. I wrote some more code which you can [try out on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtpjumwL/). The trick part definitely was that you somehow have to pass the input from the microphone through to some "destination" to get it to process.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

// TODO: Figure out what else we need and give the user feedback if he doesn't
// support microphone input.
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  captureMicrophone();
}

// First Step - Capture microphone and process the input
function captureMicrophone() {
  // process input from microphone
  const processAudio = ev =>
      processBuffer(ev.inputBuffer.getChannelData(CHANNEL));

  // setup media stream from microphone
  const microphoneStream = stream => {
    const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    microphone.connect(processor);
    // #1 If we don't pass through to speakers 'audioprocess' won't be triggerd
    processor.connect(mute);
  };
  // TODO: Handle error properly (see todo above - but probably more specific)
  const userMediaError = err => console.error(err);

  // Second step - Process buffer and output to speakers
  const processBuffer = buffer => {
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(CHANNEL).set(buffer);
    // We could move this out but that would affect audio quality
    const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(speakers);
    source.start();
  }

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const speakers = audioContext.destination;
  // We currently only operate on this channel we might need to add a couple
  // lines of code if this fact changes
  const CHANNEL = 0;
  const CHANNELS = 1;
  const BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
  const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(CHANNELS, BUFFER_SIZE, audioContext.sampleRate);

  const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFFER_SIZE, CHANNELS, CHANNELS);

  // #2 Not needed we could directly pass through to speakers since there's no
  // data anyway but just to be sure that we don't output anything
  const mute = audioContext.createGain();
  mute.gain.value = 0;
  mute.connect(speakers);

  processor.addEventListener('audioprocess', processAudio);
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, microphoneStream, userMediaError);
}

  // #2 Not needed we could directly pass through to speakers since there's no
  // data anyway but just to be sure that we don't output anything
  const mute = audioContext.createGain();
  mute.gain.value = 0;
  mute.connect(speakers);

  processor.addEventListener('audioprocess', processAudio);
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, microphoneStream, userMediaError);
}
```

The code I wrote up there looks quite dirty to me. But since you have a large project you can definitely structure it much more cleanly.

I've no clue what you're trying to achieve but I definitely also recommend to have a look at [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

### Previous answer

The main point you're missing is that you'll get an output buffer passed into `createScriptProcessor` so all the `createBuffer` stuff you do is unnecessary. Apart from that you're on the right track.

This would be a working solution. [Try it out on JSFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/bd1evk95/)

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  captureMicrophone();
}
function captureMicrophone() {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const speaker = audioContext.destination;
  const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);

  const processAudio =
      ev => {
        const CHANNEL = 0;
        const inputBuffer = ev.inputBuffer;
        const outputBuffer = ev.outputBuffer;
        const inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(CHANNEL);
        const outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(CHANNEL);

        // TODO: manually do something with the audio
        for (let i = 0; i < inputBuffer.length; ++i) {
          outputData[i] = inputData[i];
        }
      };

  const microphoneStream =
      stream => {
        const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone.connect(processor);
        processor.connect(speaker);
      };

  // TODO: handle error properly
  const userMediaError = err => console.error(err);

  processor.addEventListener('audioprocess', processAudio);
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, microphoneStream, userMediaError);
}
```

Comment: May I get a comment on the down vote so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: What you did is absolute meaningless as I did it myself. Read the question again - what I need. You fully change the logic, but I need that sequence. If I needed something simpler I would ask that question.

Comment: You should understand - there is some program I am writing now. This example is not my program, as my program is very big. So on this example I show my problem which you don't understand. In your code processor is linked to microphone and to speakers. In my code processor is not linked to speakers. What it means I need to divide program to two parts. The first (micro+processor), the second (buffer+speakers) and make them independent from each other.

Comment: Thank you for your time. You almost did it, the only problem that in my code I have one buffer which I must make work. In your code you create N buffers for every inputData. The problem is to make one buffer work adding data to it with one source node. But not to create N buffers and sources for every inputData. This is the main trick of this problem. Maybe example on this page will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode

Comment: I have two parts as I wrote above. So in the second part (speakers + ???) I need in cycle to send array of samples to speakers.As this cycle, new buffers nodes etc can't be created inside it. But the second part mustn't be linked anyhow with first part. By other words it mustn't know about microphone and processor.

Comment: I explained you what I need. In your code I don't see solution to my problem. If I don't need buffer, ok. But you didn't provide solution how to write array of samples (from microphone) to speakers without using microphone.

Comment: But play them in cycle as samples are taken from endless stream.

Comment: It it about living stream. I have said everything and have nothing to add.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the changes. Where are they?